# what's the purpose of the following about UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER?

Tags: windows, winapi

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)

UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
```

what's the purpose of UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It just suppresses a compiler warning about two parameters being unused in the function.

The macro itself is probably just defined as

```
#define UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(x) (x)
```

so it references its argument but does nothing with it.